# openshift - hostpath permission error but container not running

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

Good day.
We have noticed few nodes with hostpath permission incidents in Nagios.
Actually the path exist but no container running in that path. (upon checking uid …/pods//volume-subpaths/…)
eg:

```
DISK CRITICAL - /var/lib/openshift/openshift.local.volumes/pods/09ce34e4-9176-11e8-ba43-40f2e91e200b/volume-subpaths/volume-ymequ/selenium-hub/0 (deleted) is not accessible: No such file or directory
```

Any hint ?

Note:
Some are fixed by SELinux configuration and worked well (sample below)

```
DISK CRITICAL - /var/lib/openshift/openshift.local.volumes/pods/8de6f82a-a43e-11e8-b82a-40f2e91e22d5/volume-subpaths/eam-configuration/hellodoc/1 is not accessible: Permission denied
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the UID of the process running in the container? Have you define user while building docker image? and I think, by default the cluster has `MustRunAsRange` SCC. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/admin_guide/manage_scc.html

Comment: @Veerendra,
Thanks.
uid as shown above : 09ce34e4-9176-11e8-ba43-40f2e91e200b
thanks for that link; let me check and update you back.

Comment: `UID` - I mean User Identifier(Linux), what is the "user" or who is the owner of process?.

Comment: @Veerendra my bad, I have overlook your reply. its root